# About the questions and answers

Tags: discussion

I do have the same problem in Arduino SE, I understand that people in SE are trying to teach "how to catch the fish" and it's priceless but some answers/comments are really difficult to understand.

First because I didn't study electronics, I study Accounting! and then English is not my first language it's not even the second, it's the third language that I'm speaking.

Many users in SE community are like me, yes there are students and professionals but a big portion of users don't have the required knowledge and English is not their native language.

Please consider those before answering the questions, don't get me wrong I appreciate every bit of help even those which are vague (to me). this is not a complaint it's just a request... something to kindly consider...

Thank you.

---

<sub><sub>**Minor update:**</sub></sub>

<sup><sup>I don't mind if you vote to close this "question" (it's not a question) or I get 100 down-votes. as long as it's seen by other members. ;)</sup></sup>

Comment: Do you have an example?  Maybe the answers/comments are vague because the questions are vague.  There are users who write nearly incomprehensible answers (which turn out to be correct if you can decipher them,) but most folks try to be clear in their answers - and to teach rather than just provide a solution.

Comment: @JRE I don't want to post an example, I said what I said in general...

Comment: Well, your question here is rather vague too...

Comment: @dim changed the title.

Comment: Flagging as "too broad" since there's no example to discuss.

Answer (score 3):

The question in the title is rhetorical, since you answer it yourself in your first paragraph. And there's no other question in the body, so I'll just talk in general about the implied rant.

This site is designed to be a repository of information for engineers and other people who do engineering, including hobbyists. As such, it isn't really geared to give broad introductions to basic topics, and there are plenty of other places on the Web to get that kind of material.

Yes, students do come here to get answers to homework problems (where "homework" is defined broadly as any exercise intended to reinforce learning — including the self-imposed exercises created by hobbyists), and we try to answer those in a way that promotes the learning rather than just getting them past a particular assignment.

Comment: Can we please ditch the over-used and accusatory term 'rant' (and not replace it with anything else). It's a highly subjective claim and reads as attacking. We've many times seen the mildest points counter-attacked with 'rant'...sometimes, ironically, from those well known for ranting. The OP made a perfectly friendly question so let's address it in kind.